# Why do my generated Javadocs look terrible?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I'm trying to generate the Javadoc HTML files for my project. I'm generating them via the Maven Javadoc plugin (maven-javadoc-plugin). I am using Maven 2.2.1. Everything generates such that all the proper information is there, but the HTML looks just awful. So bad that I don't want to publish it that way. Here is a screenshot:

(**NOTE:** Yes, I see the 'JavaScript is disabled on your browser' message. Even if I click the IE 8 warning about active content and enable it, it makes no difference)

[image: Screenshot of messed up Javadoc formatting]

There are all kinds of unnecessary line breaks, and the basic formatting is just crap. Am I missing something? I was expecting to see generated Javadocs that look similar to what I see in Eclipse if I hover over a class or method and see the popup Javadoc panel.

I've tried adding setting in my POM file, but I really don't know what I'm doing when it comes to configuring the Javadoc generator. Here's what I have at the moment (inside the `<reporting>` element):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <javadocExecutable>C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javadoc.exe</javadocExecutable>
        <javadocVersion>1.7</javadocVersion>
        <locale>en_US</locale>
        <show>package</show>
        <verbose />
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE:**

The solution provided by Paulius worked perfectly. I removed the section above from my `<reporting>` section, as it was totally unnecessary. I added the new `<plugin>` element as he specified below. My POM file now contains this new block:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is what the fixed output looks like:

[image: Properly generated Javadoc]

Comment: Could it not be due to the error message at the top: *"Javascript is disabled on your browser"*?

Comment: Looks that actually "better" in your browser: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Javadoc should render without JS enabled ...

Comment: @PeterMmm Obviously there are scripts within the generated html to switch between a Javascript and non-Javascript version. I think assylias suspicion is correct.

Comment: @PeterMmm Yes, the Javadocs at that Oracle page look much better. The formatting is perfect.

Comment: Can you try to put that plugin part inside the `<build/>` tag instead and run `mvn javadoc:javadoc` to see if that makes any difference? It shouldn't but the site plugin may use another set of css files (maybe). I just tried it and I got some nice looking apidocs.

Comment: It looks markup that renders badly due to a missing stylesheet.  If you look in your browser's developer's console, does it say that it's trying to load some CSS and failing?

Comment: Java 7 api docs are not actually relevant to compare to, as it has a different HTML. 6 would be, so [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). and yes, it is using `stylesheet.css` file for styles, check for references to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `maven-javadoc-plugin` from `reporting` section. If you are using Maven 3, the reporting section is deprecated and should be removed.

Try to add the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

to your maven `plugins` section and run it. I am using `maven-javadoc-plugin` like this and it generates normal javadocs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I'm using Maven 2.2.1. I originally didn't have this block at all. I only added it to try and fix this problem.